# How can I invalidate Google Cloud CDN cache from my express server?

Tags: node.js, caching, google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cloud-cdn

Is there a way to invalidate / clear cached content on Cloud CDN from my express server?

For example, if I'm generating server rendered content to make it readily available and I update a specific route from my website, like editing a `blogPost`, for example. I need to do the following:

```
export const editBlogPostHandler = (req,res,next) => {
  // 1. UPDATE BLOGPOST WITH SLUG some-blogpost-slug ON DB
  // 2. INVALIDATE /some-blogpost-slug ROUTE ON CLOUD CDN CACHE
  // THIS IS NECESSARY FOR NEW REQUESTS TO GET FRESH DATA RATHER THAN A STALE DATA RESPONSE
};
```

How can I do that from my express server?

---

From [Cloud CDN - Invalidating Cached Content](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/invalidating-cached-content#gcloud):

You can invalidate cached content from Cloud CDN through these methods:

- Using the console:

[image]

- Using `gcloud` SDK:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715710/invalidate-google-cloud-cdn-cache-from-the-backend/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an API endpoint for that :
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps/invalidateCache

```
POST https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/global/urlMaps/{resourceId}/invalidateCache
```

Comment: Thanks. How to I get the `{resourceId}` ?

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to [Alexandre accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136849/4314588), here are more details on how to use this endpoint:

```
POST https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/global/urlMaps/{resourceId}/invalidateCache
```

1. In order to get the `resourceId`, you can call the endpoint mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps/list) in order to get a list of urlMaps resources and their associated `ids`.

   `GET https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/global/urlMaps`
2. Once you've got the `resourceId`, you also need to specify the path of the file/folder that you wish to invalidate in the request body (wildcard paths also work):

```
{ "path": "/folder/file.mp4" }
```

3. In the response body, you will find the `id` of the compute operation - If you want to check this operation progress, you can query it using the [Compute Operation Global Get method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalOperations/get).

In addition and in order to avoid running the same request several times, it is advised to give a unique `requestId` parameter under the form of a UUID (as specified in [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html))