# How can I get google cloud cdn Invalidate cache result

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

I have sent the task of clearing the cache through the python client library of google cloud cdn, and got the request id of the GCP response. However, where can I query the progress of the task of clearing the cache according to the request id.

The address where I send the request: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps/invalidateCache

The address where I send the request: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps/invalidateCache

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715710/invalidate-google-cloud-cdn-cache-from-the-backend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I query the Invalidate cache result of Google Cloud CDN through the API in the following document: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalOperations/get

And I got the information I want through the following python code：

```
def get_operation_result(gcp_request_id):
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

    service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # Project ID for this request.
    project = 'my-project'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    # Name of the Operations resource to return.
    operation = gcp_request_id  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    request = service.globalOperations().get(project=project, operation=operation)
    response = request.execute()

    # TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
    mission_status = response['status']
    return mission_status
```

Comment: lol! You're welcome, I guess. I notice that you're still calling the operation name a request ID. While request IDs are a GCP concept, they're completely separate from operation names.

Answer (score 0):

In Log Explorer, look under the `cloudaudit.googleapis.com` feed along with your request ID. You could also just filter your log explorer logs using `protoPayload.request.@type="type.googleapis.com/compute.urlMaps.invalidateCache"` to list all the invalidations made.

You may need to extend your [audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/audit-logging#enabling_audit_logging) permissions, else the information may not be visible to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query the status of a cache invalidation using the request ID; the request ID is used for deduplicating requests, not retrieving the status of an operation.

To retrieve the status of a cache invalidation, use the operation name returned in the [urlMaps.invalidateCache](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps/invalidateCache) response. You can query the status of the named operation using [globalOperations.get](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalOperations/get).

If you're using the Python client library, you can use the [GlobalOperationsClient](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/1.3.2/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.global_operations.GlobalOperationsClient) class. There's an example in gcloud's `invalidate-cdn-cache` implementation at [github.com/googleapis/python-compute/blob/main/google/cloud/compute_v1/services/url_maps/client.py](https://github.com/googleapis/python-compute/blob/90268ebbe948d6f7aa93ee65012fb6ad99505e1e/google/cloud/compute_v1/services/url_maps/client.py#L1519).